View methods of other class when accessing main class? C#
I would like to solve my problem in elegant way, rather than writing all methods of my other class into main component class (more than 100 methods)
So, in simplified version, I have unity component class:
public class MyAnimator : MonoBehaviour
{
    AnimatorHandler handler;
    public AnimatorHandler Handler => handler;
}

and the AnimatorHandler class like:
public class AnimatorHandler
{
    public void DoOperation1() { }
    public void DoOperation2() { }
    ... and a lot of more public operations
}

I would like to give user access to all DoOperation1() DoOperation2() methods of the handler class, just by accessing MyAnimator class.
Like:
    void MyUpdate(MyAnimator animator)
    {
        animator.DoOperation1();
    }

rather than
    void MyUpdate( MyAnimator animator )
    {
        animator.Handler.DoOperation1();
    }

or by writing all AnimatorHandler methods into MyAnimator, so not like:
public void DoOperation1() => handler.DoOperation1();

In such case I would end up in extra .cs file with  about 1000 lines of code and with need to update it each time I change something in the MyAnimator class.
Is there possible smart solution for such case?
Maybe possibility to return handler instead of MyAnimator instance when getting it's reference?
Thank you.

Maybe your MyAnimator class should inherit from AnimatorHandler instead?

Unfortunately, it already need to inherit from MonoBehavior to handle unity engine update loop, and other stuff.

That is simply not going to happen with the class definitions you have. One option would be to declare your AnimatorHandler class static and then make all of its methods extension methods on the MyAnimator class. MyAnimator would then have to even create an instance of AnimatorHandler. Any code that had the appropriate namespace import could inherently call all those methods as though they were members of MyAnimator. If you're interested in this option, I can provide an answer with more detail.

The problem is, I want to make MyAnimator as unneccesary part for calling AnimatorHandler methods. (when being extension, it will need MyAnimator reference)
The purpose of the AnimatorHandler, is to be able to put it inside any other class, so it don't need to know about MyAnimator existence. (so I can make different MyAnimator2 class and put AnimatorHandler inside) The MyAnimator is base class for users access + forwarding unity engine's Update loop to the AnimatorHandler.

Does this answer your question? Dynamically creating a proxy class

Have you considered using an Entity-Component-System model? It can be a bit involved to implement, but there are plenty of examples out there.

What's wrong with using a getter property? Every other "solution" is just sugercoating for the access anyways. Also, why do you have a lot of methods in the handler? Does this handle all animations for all use cases? Because that sound's like a god-object to me and I would break that down. But that doesn't help the fact that you have to access the handler via property.

"MyAnimator" is only for the example of what I need. In practice I have class with a lot of methods which are related only with the handler and it's private variables.
I was hoping there is something which would work like overload for return, or friend class but for this particular case. I think I will end up on
public void DoOperation1() => handler.DoOperation1();
within MyAnimator approach.
I want to give users instant access to these methods to make it most intuitive.

I finally ended up in interface + extensions approach.
So I made interface which just returns reference to the AnimatorHandler
and made static class with extensions methods for the interface.
In addition, AnimatorHandler also implements the interface, so desired methods can be called from AnimatorHandler itself and MyAnimator as well.
I just needed to create few internal variables/methods for the AnimatorHandler, to give more access for the extension methods calculations : unfortunately I can't put extension class inside partial class of AnimatorHandler to see private variables.

ok , let's say that the second class is attached to GameObject called player, do as follows and tell me if it works coz its my first time here:
// in the main class
public AnimatorHandler 
Animh;

void Awake()
{
//the GameObject that the main code is attached to 

GameObject player = 
GameObject.Find("player");

Animh = 
player.GetComponent<AnimatorHandler> 
();
}
void start ()
{
Animh.DoOperation1();
//or any other method that you want
}


Nah, the AnimatorHandler wil not be MonoBehaviour but default C# class, in order to have possiblity, to put it inside any kind of class.
